# Siri custom intent not working in Xamarin forms

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I have followed all the steps given in the apple Siri kit document provided,

Created API project for declaring Custom interface and Response code ,
Implemented the interface methods in Shared project
NSUseractivity is assigned to a sample view controller which is further restored in the ContinueUserActivity method.

**But the implemented intent handler methods are never been hit**

In API definition project:

```
[BaseType(typeof(INIntent))]
[Protocol]
interface OrderPartIntent
{
    [NullAllowed, Export("part", ArgumentSemantic.Copy)]
    NSString Part { get; set; }

    [NullAllowed, Export("quantity", ArgumentSemantic.Copy)]
    NSNumber Quantity { get; set; }

}

[Protocol, Model]
[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
interface IIntentHandling
{
    [Abstract]
    [Export("handleSiriCommand:completion:")]
    void HandleSiriCommand(OrderPartIntent intent, Action<SiriIntentResponse> completion);

    [Abstract]
    [Export("confirmSiriCommand:completion:")]
    void ConfirmSiriCommand(OrderPartIntent intent, Action<SiriIntentResponse> completion);
}


[BaseType(typeof(INIntentResponse))]
[Protocol]
[DisableDefaultCtor]
interface SiriIntentResponse
{
    [Export("initWithCode:userActivity:")]
    [DesignatedInitializer]
    IntPtr Constructor(IntentResponseCode code, [NullAllowed] NSUserActivity userActivity);

    [Static]
    [Export("successIntentResponseWithQuantity:quantity:")]
    SiriIntentResponse SuccessIntentResponseWithQuantity(NSString Part, NSNumber Quantity);

    [Static]
    [Export("failureUnavailableIntentResponseWithPart:")]
    SiriIntentResponse FailureUnavailableIntentResponseWithPart(NSString Part);

    [NullAllowed, Export("part", ArgumentSemantic.Copy)]
    NSString Part { get; set; }

    [NullAllowed, Export("quantity", ArgumentSemantic.Copy)]
    NSNumber Quantity { get; set; }

    [Export("code")]
    IntentResponseCode Code { get; }
}
```

In shared project, the above interfaces are implemented as below:

```
   override public void HandleSiriCommand(OrderPartIntent intent,Action<SiriIntentResponse> completion)
    {
       //Given some hardcoded values for now
        completion(SiriIntentResponse.SuccessIntentResponseWithQuantity(new NSString("Success value"), new NSNumber(2)));
    }

    override public void ConfirmSiriCommand(OrderPartIntent intent, Action<SiriIntentResponse> completion)
    {
        completion(SiriIntentResponse.SuccessIntentResponseWithQuantity(new NSString("Success value"), new NSNumber(2)));
    }
```

IntentDefinition file goes like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>INEnums</key>
    <array/>
    <key>INIntentDefinitionModelVersion</key>
    <string>1.2</string>
    <key>INIntentDefinitionNamespace</key>
    <string>xNas9K</string>
    <key>INIntentDefinitionSystemVersion</key>
    <string>21A559</string>
    <key>INIntentDefinitionToolsBuildVersion</key>
    <string>13C100</string>
    <key>INIntentDefinitionToolsVersion</key>
    <string>13.2.1</string>
    <key>INIntents</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>INIntentCategory</key>
            <string>order</string>
            <key>INIntentConfigurable</key>
            <true/>
            <key>INIntentDescription</key>
            <string>Order gear part </string>
            <key>INIntentDescriptionID</key>
            <string>Jcr2iw</string>
            <key>INIntentInput</key>
            <string>part</string>
            <key>INIntentKeyParameter</key>
            <string>quantity</string>
            <key>INIntentLastParameterTag</key>
            <integer>3</integer>
            <key>INIntentManagedParameterCombinations</key>
            <dict>
                <key>part,quantity</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>INIntentParameterCombinationSupportsBackgroundExecution</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>INIntentParameterCombinationTitle</key>
                    <string>Order ${quantity}${part}</string>
                    <key>INIntentParameterCombinationTitleID</key>
                    <string>GYl7RW</string>
                    <key>INIntentParameterCombinationUpdatesLinked</key>
                    <true/>
                </dict>
            </dict>
            <key>INIntentName</key>
            <string>OrderPart</string>
            <key>INIntentParameterCombinations</key>
            <dict>
                <key>part,quantity</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>INIntentParameterCombinationIsLinked</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>INIntentParameterCombinationSupportsBackgroundExecution</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>INIntentParameterCombinationTitle</key>
                    <string>Order ${quantity}${part}</string>
                    <key>INIntentParameterCombinationTitleID</key>
                    <string>i9T3Xg</string>
                </dict>
            </dict>
            <key>INIntentParameters</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>INIntentParameterConfigurable</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>INIntentParameterDisplayName</key>
                    <string>Part</string>
                    <key>INIntentParameterDisplayNameID</key>
                    <string>lCDrSv</string>
                    <key>INIntentParameterDisplayPriority</key>
                    <integer>1</integer>
                    <key>INIntentParameterMetadata</key>
                    <dict>
                        <key>INIntentParameterMetadataCapitalization</key>
                        <string>Sentences</string>
                        <key>INIntentParameterMetadataDefaultValueID</key>
                        <string>FQrMNA</string>
                    </dict>
                    <key>INIntentParameterName</key>
                    <string>part</string>
                    <key>INIntentParameterPromptDialogs</key>
                    <array>
                        <dict>
                            <key>INIntentParameterPromptDialogCustom</key>
                            <true/>
                            <key>INIntentParameterPromptDialogType</key>
                            <string>Configuration</string>
                        </dict>
                        <dict>
                            <key>INIntentParameterPromptDialogCustom</key>
                            <true/>
                            <key>INIntentParameterPromptDialogFormatString</key>
                            <string>Which part you want?</string>
                            <key>INIntentParameterPromptDialogFormatStringID</key>
                            <string>agn15v</string>
                            <key>INIntentParameterPromptDialogType</key>
                            <string>Primary</string>
                        </dict>
                    </array>
                    <key>INIntentParameterSupportsResolution</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>INIntentParameterTag</key>
                    <integer>1</integer>
                    <key>INIntentParameterType</key>
                    <string>String</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>INIntentParameterConfigurable</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>INIntentParameterCustomDisambiguation</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>INIntentParameterDisplayName</key>
                    <string>Quantity</string>
                    <key>INIntentParameterDisplayNameID</key>
                    <string>YU4AQ6</string>
                    <key>INIntentParameterDisplayPriority</key>
                    <integer>2</integer>
                    <key>INIntentParameterMetadata</key>
                    <dict>
                        <key>INIntentParameterMetadataDefaultValue</key>
                        <integer>1</integer>
                        <key>INIntentParameterMetadataMaximumValue</key>
                        <integer>10</integer>
                        <key>INIntentParameterMetadataMinimumValue</key>
                        <integer>1</integer>
                        <key>INIntentParameterMetadataType</key>
                        <string>Field</string>
                    </dict>
                    <key>INIntentParameterName</key>
                    <string>quantity</string>
                    <key>INIntentParameterPromptDialogs</key>
                    <array>
                        <dict>
                            <key>INIntentParameterPromptDialogCustom</key>
                            <true/>
                            <key>INIntentParameterPromptDialogType</key>
                            <string>Configuration</string>
                        </dict>
                        <dict>
                            <key>INIntentParameterPromptDialogCustom</key>
                            <true/>
                            <key>INIntentParameterPromptDialogFormatString</key>
                            <string>How many ${part}do you want?</string>
                            <key>INIntentParameterPromptDialogFormatStringID</key>
                            <string>TxdgVC</string>
                            <key>INIntentParameterPromptDialogType</key>
                            <string>Primary</string>
                        </dict>
                        <dict>
                            <key>INIntentParameterPromptDialogCustom</key>
                            <true/>
                            <key>INIntentParameterPromptDialogFormatString</key>
                            <string>Just to confirm, you wanted ‘${quantity}’?</string>
                            <key>INIntentParameterPromptDialogFormatStringID</key>
                            <string>2smwR0</string>
                            <key>INIntentParameterPromptDialogType</key>
                            <string>Confirmation</string>
                        </dict>
                    </array>
                    <key>INIntentParameterSupportsResolution</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>INIntentParameterTag</key>
                    <integer>3</integer>
                    <key>INIntentParameterType</key>
                    <string>Integer</string>
                    <key>INIntentParameterUnsupportedReasons</key>
                    <array>
                        <dict>
                            <key>INIntentParameterUnsupportedReasonCode</key>
                            <string>negativeNumbersNotSupported</string>
                            <key>INIntentParameterUnsupportedReasonDefault</key>
                            <true/>
                            <key>INIntentParameterUnsupportedReasonFormatString</key>
                            <string>${displayName} can’t be negative.</string>
                            <key>INIntentParameterUnsupportedReasonFormatStringID</key>
                            <string>FCTaXZ</string>
                        </dict>
                        <dict>
                            <key>INIntentParameterUnsupportedReasonCode</key>
                            <string>greaterThanMaximumValue</string>
                            <key>INIntentParameterUnsupportedReasonDefault</key>
                            <true/>
                            <key>INIntentParameterUnsupportedReasonFormatString</key>
                            <string>${displayName} can’t be higher than ${maximumValue}.</string>
                            <key>INIntentParameterUnsupportedReasonFormatStringID</key>
                            <string>HJpMVY</string>
                        </dict>
                        <dict>
                            <key>INIntentParameterUnsupportedReasonCode</key>
                            <string>lessThanMinimumValue</string>
                            <key>INIntentParameterUnsupportedReasonDefault</key>
                            <true/>
                            <key>INIntentParameterUnsupportedReasonFormatString</key>
                            <string>${displayName} can’t be lower than ${minimumValue}.</string>
                            <key>INIntentParameterUnsupportedReasonFormatStringID</key>
                            <string>IHZTRu</string>
                        </dict>
                    </array>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>INIntentResponse</key>
            <dict>
                <key>INIntentResponseCodes</key>
                <array>
                    <dict>
                        <key>INIntentResponseCodeFormatString</key>
                        <string>Your ${part} is successfully ordered</string>
                        <key>INIntentResponseCodeFormatStringID</key>
                        <string>8SBdtE</string>
                        <key>INIntentResponseCodeName</key>
                        <string>success</string>
                        <key>INIntentResponseCodeSuccess</key>
                        <true/>
                    </dict>
                    <dict>
                        <key>INIntentResponseCodeFormatString</key>
                        <string>Your order failed</string>
                        <key>INIntentResponseCodeFormatStringID</key>
                        <string>iIPZ9u</string>
                        <key>INIntentResponseCodeName</key>
                        <string>failure</string>
                    </dict>
                </array>
                <key>INIntentResponseLastParameterTag</key>
                <integer>3</integer>
                <key>INIntentResponseOutput</key>
                <string>part</string>
                <key>INIntentResponseParameters</key>
                <array>
                    <dict>
                        <key>INIntentResponseParameterDisplayName</key>
                        <string>Part</string>
                        <key>INIntentResponseParameterDisplayNameID</key>
                        <string>z6G4Na</string>
                        <key>INIntentResponseParameterDisplayPriority</key>
                        <integer>1</integer>
                        <key>INIntentResponseParameterName</key>
                        <string>part</string>
                        <key>INIntentResponseParameterTag</key>
                        <integer>1</integer>
                        <key>INIntentResponseParameterType</key>
                        <string>String</string>
                    </dict>
                    <dict>
                        <key>INIntentResponseParameterDisplayName</key>
                        <string>Quantity</string>
                        <key>INIntentResponseParameterDisplayNameID</key>
                        <string>PpK7U0</string>
                        <key>INIntentResponseParameterDisplayPriority</key>
                        <integer>2</integer>
                        <key>INIntentResponseParameterName</key>
                        <string>quantity</string>
                        <key>INIntentResponseParameterTag</key>
                        <integer>3</integer>
                        <key>INIntentResponseParameterType</key>
                        <string>Integer</string>
                    </dict>
                </array>
            </dict>
            <key>INIntentRestrictions</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>INIntentTitle</key>
            <string>Order Part</string>
            <key>INIntentTitleID</key>
            <string>P0Xi5J</string>
            <key>INIntentType</key>
            <string>Custom</string>
            <key>INIntentUserConfirmationRequired</key>
            <true/>
            <key>INIntentVerb</key>
            <string>Order</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>INTypes</key>
    <array/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**Can anyone please help me on getting the intent data through the AppDelegate *ContinueUserActivity* method from *NSUserActivity* parameter or suggest me the proper way to achieve this?**

```
public override bool ContinueUserActivity(UIApplication application, NSUserActivity userActivity, UIApplicationRestorationHandler completionHandler)
    { }
```

Comment: Do you use bindinglibrary? Have you seen this guide? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/walkthrough?tabs=macos

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).